# MVC C# download multiple files from remote path passing network credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I have a web page (MVC) that displays a list of files. each file has a date against it. I want users to be able to select start and end date and hit a button that would automatically download all files (from a remote server having to pass network credentials) within the date range as a zip file onto their machine with usual browser download notification.
What is the best way of doing this?

I found this library Ionic.Zip but I don't know to pass network credentials to it.

```
using Ionic.Zip; 

public void DownloadMultiple(List<string> fileUrls) 
{ 
    // Use NetworkCredential ??? 
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) 
    { 
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;  
        zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files"); 
        foreach (string url in fileUrls) 
        { 
            zip.AddFile(url, "Files"); 
        } 

        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false; 
        string zipName = "CB_Invoice.zip"; 
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip"; 
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName); 
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream); 
        Response.End(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear, do you mean you want to select a group of files within a date range and zip them, only allowing the client to download them if the client is authenticated? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry about that. I need code for the Download controller action method to do the following: 1) know which files to be downloaded (done - have a list of file names). 2) set network credential (username, password, domain) 3) download all files looping through the list and make them a zip file.

Comment: @Layla Please post what you already have. Have you tried this? Have you written code and it does not work? StackOverflow does not work like this. Please read the SO question policy (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Layla Zip libraries don't take network credentials as arguments. They are used to compress files using a compression algorithm. It looks like you want to GET (That's a hint) the files to compress before you can zip them.